# 'npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false...' why do I need to run this every time for my release APK to update?

Tags: android, react-native

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

or

```
./gradlew app:assembleRelease --warning-mode all
```

doesn't update the code changes to the APK/build.

**I am not running on an emulator**. I am running release APK on a physical device.

what seems to be working for me to get the updated APK is the following command

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

then I have to delete

**drawables-*** folders and **raw** folder from `Project/android/app/src/main/res`

Once I have done the above steps, if I try building a release, the code updates properly.

It's a pain to do this every time I update the code. **Can anybody tell me why this is happening and how I can fix this issue?**

Thanks in advance.

**I think the issue started when I changed my MacBook. I also updated Android studio to the latest version.**

```
"react-native": "0.63.2",
Android Studio 4.2
```

Comment: Try to debug the build process .

Comment: @gwl002 can you explain it in detail please? I'm not sure how to do it. Since the build always completes without any errors.

Comment: Try creating a new project and copy the js is more quick.

Comment: @gwl002 I'm not sure that is an option since it's an app in production. I don't want to mess anything up.